# TypeScript infer about array[index]

Tags: typescript

I expected `result` is `number | never[]`.
But actually `number | never[] | undefined`.

```
type T1 = (number | undefined)[]

const myFunc = (arr: T1, index: number) => {
    const result = arr[index] === undefined ? [] : arr[index]
    return result // number | never[] | undefined
}
```

Why does it behave like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript uses flow analysis to narrow down types of variables.
However, it seems unable to narrow down `arr` just by checking that one of the elements is undefined:

```
type T1 = (number | undefined)[]
const myFunc = (arr: T1, index: number) => {
    if (arr[index] === undefined) {
        return []; // never[]
    }
    //the type of `arr` is still considered T1
    let temp = arr[index]; //number | undefined 
    return temp;
}
```

Actually, I'm not sure how else should the type of `arr` be represented as after the `if` block (how would you represent "an array of number|undefined, except that this particular dynamic index is not undefined"?). It still makes some sense to simply fall back to `T1`.

Your code uses ternary operator, but it acts similarly to my code above.

However, TypeScript can narrow down the types for a `result` variable when the variable is used in a direct comparison in a flow control statement:

```
type T1 = (number | undefined)[]
const myFunc = (arr: T1, index: number) => {
    const result = arr[index];
    if (result === undefined) {
        return []; // never[]
    }
    //the type of `result` is correctly determined as number, not undefined
    return result;
}
```

I think `arr` and `result` (variables) may have their types narrowed down by control flow, but `arr[index]` (an expression, not just a variable) will just be computed from the types of `arr` and `index` at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like TypeScript needs some help to infer types correctly based on your ternary expression. You can fix it in two ways:

Introduce a variable

```
const myFunc = (arr: T1, index: number) => {
    const value = arr[index];
    const result = value === undefined ? [] : value;
    return result // number | never[]
}
```

Use the non-null assertion operator to help the compiler understand that the value will never be undefined:

```
const myFunc = (arr: T1, index: number) => {
    const result = arr[index] === undefined ? [] : arr[index]!
    return result // number | never[]
}
```